# Can you say "bald hill" to mean a hill that has no trees on it?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, translation, russian

I am translating from Russian to English, and came across the phrase "На краю долины на вершине лысого холма стоит [...]" -  trying to describe a hill at the edge of a valley. I've never come across "bald hill" anywhere in English. To me, it could be read literally like a hill that has no hair on it, but it could also be quickly parsed to mean a hill that is empty and clear of trees. Would most English readers understand this meaning, or would they laugh at the phrase?

Comment: "Bald hill" would mean to me _a hill with no vegetation, including grass_. _**Treeless**_ would be more accurate, but I am not sure it fits your tone... Maybe _**bare**_?

Comment: I would go further than fev - I would say a bald hill is a hill whose top is completely covered by sheets of rock, e.g. Mount Kailash (Кайлас)

Comment: I would say that a *bald hill* has no trees *on its top*, while a *bare hill* has no trees *anywhere* on it. But maybe I'm extending the metaphor farther than most English speakers would.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is general reference. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bald) **bald**: 
1a: lacking a natural or usual covering (as of hair, vegetation, or nap)
his bald head // 
Both men were bald. '' 
a bald hill

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Bald*** means

> with little or no hair on the head ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bald))

so metaphorically, it would describe the hill as *having no vegetation, not even grass.* A hill of solid earth, or a hill after a huge fire that burnt everything. Maybe @Greybeard's suggestion of *covered by sheets of rock* is plausible, too, though I haven't thought of it when I first read the expression.

As I said in a comment, ***[treeless](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/treeless)*** is more accurate, but does not seem to correspond to the poetic tone I feel in the Russian sentence.

I would go for ***bare*** which means:

> lacking a natural, usual, or appropriate covering ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bare))

Bare is used even technically to describe treeless hills. There is a book called

> [Regreening the Bare Hills](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789048198696) (about the *Tropical Forest Restoration in the Asia-Pacific Region*)

Here is a somewhat poetic use of the expression ***bare hills***:

> ...flowing between ***bare hills***, without a tree or a thicket on its banks... ([The Eclectic review](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mOEEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA147&dq=%22bare%20hills%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0jo-hxr_yAhXTnVwKHbPTBUk4HhDoATADegQICxAC))

ADDITION: Thanks to @Kate Bunting's interesting comment, here is an insight in the matter:

> *Night on Bald Mountain* (Russian: *Ночь на лысой горе*, romanized: Noch′ na lysoy gore), also known as *Night on the Bare Mountain*, is a series of compositions by Modest Mussorgsky (1839–1881).
>
> ***Bald Mountain*** is the most familiar translation of "***лысой горе***" (lysoy gore) in English, and is also the most literal. The adjective "bald" is commonly used in English place names for ***barren hills, mountains***, and other features, and so is also idiomatic. ***However, because the most familiar use of "bald" describes hairlessness, this part of the title is also known as "Bare Mountain".*** The use of "bald" to describe barren landscapes is common in European languages. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_on_Bald_Mountain))

I agree that *bald* is closer to *barren*, whereas *bare* has a certain vagueness that is welcome in this context.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I knew I was forgetting about some similar word to bald - bare! CAT tools sometimes fail spectacularly :)

Comment: I don't speak Russian, but I know that Mussorgsky's composition usually known in English as _Night on the Bare Mountain_ is occasionally called _Night on Bald Mountain_.

Comment: @fev It's a musical composition, not a book. Apparently the Russian title is  Иванова ночь на лысой горе.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, I did not know, though it is clearly stated in the link I provided. I went straight to the comments about the name of the composition. Thank you, I am always grateful to learn something new.

Comment: @KateBunting - I've always known the Mussorgsky composition as *Night on Bald Mountain* and that's the way it's referred to in [Disney's *Fantasia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasia_(1940_film)#Night_on_Bald_Mountain_and_Ave_Maria); but I'd say that it has always come across to me (as a native English speaker) as the proper name of a particular mountain, just because it doesn't sound like a description I'd normally use.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - Yes, when I looked up the Russian title I was surprised to find that 'Bald' seems to predominate online. I've always known it as 'Bare' and that is the version listed in the Concise Oxford Dictionary of Music. Maybe it's a transatlantic difference?

Comment: Bald doesn't even mean BALD for hair (e.g. Prince William is surely bald). A quick search of "Bald Hill" and (yes) "Bald Mountain" turns up a ton of places named such, image search reveals that these are of varying degrees of baldness.

Comment: "bald" is an entirely acceptable adjective for use in describing a hill or mountain, to mean "without trees or shrubs", in English. It is also, as has been noted, sometimes used as a noun for such places.

Comment: In the Southern Appalacians, it has a very specific meaning. [Balds](https://www.belmetric.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=8965&cPath=3_280_1453&gclid=Cj0KCQjwpf2IBhDkARIsAGVo0D2b6CfWTahSrVO8vHJ_ZzAn5ffG4Sp7JGEccqKcIpGG95o4oKBh-LYaAnJjEALw_wcB&zenid=iajl8djjusruk58u5glqdcu4f5)

Comment: @KateBunting "Night on Bald Mountain" is what I first read on a CD, of so many years ago.  When I picture it, I think of treeless/shrubless, not grassless.

Answer (score 7):

The very first definition in Merriam-Webster [[link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bald)] is:

> **:** lacking a natural or usual covering (as of hair, **vegetation**, or [nap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nap#h3))

(emphasis mine), and one of its examples is indeed "a *bald* hill".

That said, despite what the above definition might seem to imply, a "bald hill" may just be treeless [[example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bald_Hills,_Victoria)], rather than lacking *all* vegetation, or may even just be treeless *at the summit* [[example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bald_Hill_(Oregon))], in the same way that a "bald man" might lack hair only on the top of his head. Incidentally, Merriam-Webster doesn't mention this, but hills that are treeless at the summit are sometimes called *balds* (as a noun) [[example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_balds)], as are ones that are completely bare of vegetation [[example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamma_Hamma_Balds_Natural_Area_Preserve)].

I would guess that relatively few English-speakers are consciously aware of these uses, but I would expect most people to understand the idea in context. The exact phrase "a bald hill" appears in many books [[link](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+bald+hill%22&tbm=bks)]. (But it's not as common as "a bare hill" [[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+bald+hill%2Ca+bare+hill&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20bald%20hill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bare%20hill%3B%2Cc0)].)

Answer (score 1):

A hill like the one you describe I'd call a **fell**.
Interestingly, [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fell) uses the word **barren** to describe the superficial features, meaning no – or very few – trees, but still some vegetation, typically moorland, so peat bogs, shrubs, grass etc.

Fell is a fairly specialized term, though, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fell) even calls it archaic:

> fell (plural fells)
>
> 1. (archaic outside Britain) A rocky ridge or chain of mountains.
> 2. (archaic outside Britain) A wild field or upland moor.

Familiar to someone living in the northern parts of Great Britain, but less so to a typical North American I'd guess. Depending on the intended audience the more intuitive **barren hill**, as used by Wikipedia, might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The US has a fair number of "Mount Baldy" mountains.  They are places that stick up above the local treeline.